# MacBook dead; get music from an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, music, data-transfer

My mom's MacBook Air recently bit the dust and thus took all her music with it. Since I do not own an adapter for the old SSD, it's been sent to archive first for when I get a proper adapter again. Problem is though that she still has a lot of music on her phone and would now like to burn a CD from it. With the problem of cost for a new car radio and the inevitable purchase of a new machine and adapter case for the old SSD, it would be cheaper to first take all the music from her iPhone to my Windows maschine and burn a CD here.

Problem is, most of the software I find online sound scammy and have insane prices for their full version. Knowing that there are open source reimplementation of MobileDevice libraries, I was wondering if there was a way to just get the music off her phone?

She has set aside but a single playlist with all the songs she wants to have burnt to a CD - so, all that I want to do is copy said playlist and songs within to my PC and burn that. I know how to do everything except get the music off the device.

It's unfortunate that there are many scammy products out there and it's hard to figure out which one of those is legitimately useful and which ones are just pure garbage... I am not looking for a software recommendation - but a method to simply get the songs from her phone so I can burn that CD for her.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Depending on what's wrong with the macbook, it might be easier to try to get the music from there. Have you tried booting into Target Disk Mode?

Comment: @Cody Motherboard failure. When I took it apart to check what was broken, even the pinstrips on the ribbon cables were peeling off - in the magnitude of centimeters. That MacBook had been used for about 10ish years. I think MacBookAir3,2 was the id.